# How to access a method of another class in another file which is in same package in java?

Tags: java, class, oop, package

Myclass.java

```
package mypackage;


import java.util.*;
public class Myclass{
    public static void add(int a,int b){
            System.out.println(a+b);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("success");
    }
}
```

Good.java

```
package mypackage;


public class Good{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Myclass obj = new Myclass();
        obj.add(2,3);
    }
}
```

how to access add method in Myclass in Good class?

Error I am encountering while compiling

```
Good.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                Myclass obj = new Myclass();
                ^
  symbol:   class Myclass
  location: class Good
Good.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                Myclass obj = new Myclass();
                                  ^
  symbol:   class Myclass
  location: class Good
2 errors
```

Comment: This should work in general. How are you compiling your code?

Comment: Are the .java files in the same directory?

Comment: yes both are in same folder @VGR

Comment: @T_01 javac Good.java - compiling this way

Comment: Well you have to tell the compiler what classes you are dealing with: You are only telling it "compile A" so it does not now about B. Try: `javac A.java B.java` or javac `*.java`. Consider also `man javac` on linux or [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html).

Answer (score 0):

Well, The code is running perfectly in my system but there are some points for your cross verification:

1. I think Myclass.java file is not able to be recognized in Good.java class. So, please check that all *.java files are in the same folder.
2. It is not required to use the *import java.utill.*;* in Myclass.

I hope it will be helpful.
Note: Any issue or suggestion finding, please let me know in coomment.